# JQuery trying to check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check a check box with jquery alone and then doing a return false as there is other jquery methods i dont want to affect the check box. But for some reason the check box is not checking or unchecking. I need the return false in there as there is other functions which affect the outside element of the checkbox.

```
 $("#p h1 input").click(function (event) {

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }

    return false;
});
```

ok additional i have this even on the h1

```
$("#p h1").click(function (event) {
        $(this).next(".content").slideToggle();

        if ($(this).hasClass("on")) {
            $(this).find("span").addClass("fa-angle-up");
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("fa-angle-down");
        }
        else {
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("fa-angle-up");
            $(this).find("span").addClass("fa-angle-down");
        }

        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
```

The check box is inside the h1.

I don't want the slide function or anything from the second click event to occur when the checkbox is clicked.

This is the html

```
<h1>Set<span class="fa fa-angle-up"></span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Confirm)</h1>
```

Comment: You are checking the checkbox and at the same time the click event uncheck the same checkbox that is why nothing is happening. Because `$(this)` refers to the checkbox and the selector `$("#p h1 input")` also seems to be a checkbox

Comment: Why are you doing this? The checkbox does this itself when you click on it. Your JS is just interfering with that process and messing it up. Your question may be better if you gave us details of the problem you're trying to solve as I can guarantee you there is a better way than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want the slide function or anything from the second click event to occur when the checkbox is clicked.

In this case you can check what the `target` of the event was, and not perform your logic if it was the checkbox. To do this you can use jQuery's `is()` function.

Also note that your `if` logic can be simplified by simply using `toggleClass()` instead. Try this:

```js
$("#p h1").click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(':checkbox'))
    return;

  var $h1 = $(this);
  $h1.next(".content").slideToggle();
  $h1.toggleClass('on').find('span').toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="p">
  <h1 class="on">
    Set
    <span class="fa fa-angle-up"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Confirm" />
  </h1>
</div>
```